# Scraping an AJAX page using VBA

Tags: json, vba, excel, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest

I've been trying to Scrape the *entire* HTML body and assign it as a string variable before manipulating that string to populate an excel file - this will be done on a a loop to update the date every 5 minute interval.

These pages are AJAX pages, so run what looks like JavaScript (I'm not familiar with JS at all though).

I've tried using the `XMLHttpRequest` object (code below) but t returns the JS Calls:

```
Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
XMLHTTP.Open "GET", "https://www.google.co.uk/finance?ei=bQ_iWLnjOoS_UeWcqsgE", False
XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
XMLHTTP.send
Debug.Print XMLHTTP.ResponseText
```

I've tried creating an `IE` object with the below code but, again, same issue:

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = False
IE.navigate "https://www.google.co.uk/finance?ei=bQ_iWLnjOoS_UeWcqsgE"
While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
Set HTMLdoc = IE.Document
Debug.Print = HTMLdoc.Body.innerHTML
```

What I want it exactly text available to me when I hit F12 and got to the inspector tab (ie. the entirety of the text within the yellow section below) - If I could get this (full expanded) I could work from there. Any help would be massively appreciated.

[image]

In the above example (Google finance), the index prices update asynchronously - I want to capture these at the time at which I assign the string.

Comment: Could you please add to your question the expected output? It's not quite clear what is the exact text is available for you in Developer Tools.

Comment: @omegastripes I've included the final sentence - if for example i'm look for the CAC 40 (the French stock exchange) value, I currently can't extract it as it's not contained within `Debug.print`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any dynamically loaded data you just inspect XHRs the webpage does, find the one containing the relevant data, make the same XHR (either site provides API or not) and parse response, or in case of IE automation you add extra wait loop until a target element becomes accessible, then retrieve it from DOM.

In that certain case you can get the data via Google Finance API.

Method 1.

To make the request you have to know stock symbols, which could be easily find within webpage HTML content, or e. g. if you click on CAC 40, in opened page there will be a title CAC 40 (INDEXEURO:PX1).

There are the following stock and stock exchange symbols in the World markets table on that page:

```
Shanghai            SHA:000001
S&P 500             INDEXSP:.INX
Nikkei 225          INDEXNIKKEI:NI225
Hang Seng Index     INDEXHANGSENG:HSI
TSEC                TPE:TAIEX
EURO STOXX 50       INDEXSTOXX:SX5E
CAC 40              INDEXEURO:PX1
S&P TSX             INDEXTSI:OSPTX
S&P/ASX 200         INDEXASX:XJO
BSE Sensex          INDEXBOM:SENSEX
SMI                 INDEXSWX:SMI
ATX                 INDEXVIE:ATX
IBOVESPA            INDEXBVMF:IBOV
SET                 INDEXBKK:SET
BIST100             INDEXIST:XU100
IBEX                INDEXBME:IB
WIG                 WSE:WIG
TASI                TADAWUL:TASI
MERVAL              BCBA:IAR
IPC                 INDEXBMV:ME
IDX Composite       IDX:COMPOSITE
```

Put them into URL:

http://finance.google.com/finance/info?q=SHA:000001,INDEXSP:.INX,INDEXNIKKEI:NI225,INDEXHANGSENG:HSI,TPE:TAIEX,INDEXSTOXX:SX5E,INDEXEURO:PX1,INDEXTSI:OSPTX,INDEXASX:XJO,INDEXBOM:SENSEX,INDEXSWX:SMI,INDEXVIE:ATX,INDEXBVMF:IBOV,INDEXBKK:SET,INDEXIST:XU100,INDEXBME:IB,WSE:WIG,TADAWUL:TASI,BCBA:IAR,INDEXBMV:ME,IDX:COMPOSITE

The response contains JSON data, like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": "7521596",
        "t": "000001",
        "e": "SHA",
        "l": "3,222.51",
        "l_fix": "3222.51",
        "l_cur": "CN¥3,222.51",
        "s": "0",
        "ltt": "3:01PM GMT+8",
        "lt": "Mar 31, 3:01PM GMT+8",
        "lt_dts": "2017-03-31T15:01:15Z",
        "c": "+12.28",
        "c_fix": "12.28",
        "cp": "0.38",
        "cp_fix": "0.38",
        "ccol": "chg",
        "pcls_fix": "3210.2368"
    },
    ...
]
```

You may use the below VBA code to parse response and output result. It requires [JSON.bas](https://github.com/omegastripes/VBA-JSON-parser) module to be imported to VBA project for JSON processing.

```vb
Sub GoogleFinanceData()

    Dim sJSONString As String
    Dim vJSON As Variant
    Dim sState As String
    Dim aData()
    Dim aHeader()

    ' Retrieve Google Finance data
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "http://finance.google.com/finance/info?q=SHA:000001,INDEXSP:.INX,INDEXNIKKEI:NI225,INDEXHANGSENG:HSI,TPE:TAIEX,INDEXSTOXX:SX5E,INDEXEURO:PX1,INDEXTSI:OSPTX,INDEXASX:XJO,INDEXBOM:SENSEX,INDEXSWX:SMI,INDEXVIE:ATX,INDEXBVMF:IBOV,INDEXBKK:SET,INDEXIST:XU100,INDEXBME:IB,WSE:WIG,TADAWUL:TASI,BCBA:IAR,INDEXBMV:ME,IDX:COMPOSITE", False
        .Send
        If .Status <> 200 Then Exit Sub
        sJSONString = .responseText
    End With
    ' Trim extraneous chars
    sJSONString = Mid(sJSONString, InStr(sJSONString, "["))
    ' Parse JSON string
    JSON.Parse sJSONString, vJSON, sState
    If sState = "Error" Then Exit Sub
    ' Convert to table format
    JSON.ToArray vJSON, aData, aHeader
    ' Results output
    With Sheets(1)
        .Cells.Delete
        .Cells.WrapText = False
        If UBound(aHeader) >= 0 Then OutputArray .Cells(1, 1), aHeader
        Output2DArray .Cells(2, 1), aData
        .Columns.AutoFit
    End With

End Sub

Sub OutputArray(oDstRng As Range, aCells As Variant)

    With oDstRng
        .Parent.Select
        With .Resize(1, UBound(aCells) - LBound(aCells) + 1)
            .NumberFormat = "@"
            .Value = aCells
        End With
    End With

End Sub

Sub Output2DArray(oDstRng As Range, aCells As Variant)

    With oDstRng
        .Parent.Select
        With .Resize( _
                UBound(aCells, 1) - LBound(aCells, 1) + 1, _
                UBound(aCells, 2) - LBound(aCells, 2) + 1)
            .NumberFormat = "@"
            .Value = aCells
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

As a result the data you need is located in `l_fix`, `c_fix`, `cp_fix` columns.

Method 2.

Also you can make XHR by the URL like this one for CAC 40:

https://www.google.co.uk/finance/getprices?q=PX1&x=INDEXEURO&i=120&p=20m&f=d,c,v,o,h,l

Particularly that URL is for PX1 stock and INDEXEURO stock exchange symbols, 120 sec interval, 20 minutes period, response data d,c,v,o,h,l is for DATE (UNIX TimeStamp), CLOSE, VOLUME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW.

Response format is as follows:

```
EXCHANGE%3DINDEXEURO
MARKET_OPEN_MINUTE=540
MARKET_CLOSE_MINUTE=1050
INTERVAL=120
COLUMNS=DATE,CLOSE,HIGH,LOW,OPEN,VOLUME
DATA=
TIMEZONE_OFFSET=120
a1491405000,5098.75,5099.92,5098.75,5099.92,0
1,5100.51,5100.51,5098.09,5098.09,0
2,5099.63,5101.2,5099.29,5100.68,0
3,5099.83,5100.04,5099.07,5099.28,0
4,5098.19,5098.9,5097.71,5098.9,0
5,5098.56,5099.24,5097.99,5099.24,0
6,5097.34,5098.2,5096.14,5098.2,0
7,5096.52,5097.38,5095.66,5097.38,0
8,5093.27,5095.39,5093.27,5095.39,0
9,5094.43,5094.43,5092.07,5093.17,0
10,5088.18,5092.72,5087.68,5092.72,0
```

The XHR should be done for each stock symbol in the list, then results should be consolidated into table.

Comment: Thanks for this. The problem I have is while Google has an API, this is just an example and the majority of the web pages don't have API so this isn't something I can do for them. Are there any other ways around this?

Comment: @Jeremy could you please provide another website URL that you need to scrape, and which doesn't provide an API, just for example? I would try to state some general guidelines.

Comment: I've since got my head around CSS `querySelectorAll`, and also looping through elements within Parentelements (I didn't know this could be done in the same way you could `for each` loop ranges within a range) so problem solved - You get best answer for trying to help! Thanks :)