# Scrape with xmlhttp

Tags: excel, vba, xmlhttprequest, scrape

I would like to get data from https://www.goaloong.net/football/6in1
This page contains a table.

I tried with:

```
Sub REQUESTXML()

Dim XMLHttpRequest As xmlHttp
Dim HTMLDoc As New HTMLDocument
Dim elem As Object
Dim x As Long

Set XMLHttpRequest = New MSXML2.xmlHttp
XMLHttpRequest.Open "GET", "https://www.goaloong.net/football/6in1", False
XMLHttpRequest.send
While XMLHttpRequest.readyState = 200
    DoEvents
Wend

Debug.Print XMLHttpRequest.responseText
HTMLDoc.Body.innerHTML = XMLHttpRequest.responseText

x = 1

For Each elem In HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("Leaguestitle")

    Sheets("req").Range("A" & x).Value = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("a")(0).innerText
    
 x = x + 1
 
 Next elem

 End Sub
```

I have no result.

Kindly help me?

Answer (score 0):

The page https://www.goaloong.net/football/6in1 is dynamic, i.e. first the java scripts are loaded, then the scripts are loading the content. One approach is to load the full page content in IE and get it out of it. Example below (tested):

```
Sub REQUESTXML()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
    Dim elem As Object
    Dim x As Long
    
    IE.navigate "https://www.goaloong.net/football/6in1"
    
    Do While IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop
    Do Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop
    
    'for debug purpose
    Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\TESTFILE.html" For Output As #1
    Print #1, IE.document.body.innerHTML
    Close #1
    
    x = 1
    For Each elem In IE.document.getElementsByClassName("Leaguestitle")
        Sheets(1).Range("A" & x).Value = elem.innerText
        x = x + 1
    Next elem

    IE.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, it works with IE but i would like to use xmlhttp, IE is too slow. Anyway i need all table. Alternatives?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43183637/scraping-an-ajax-page-using-vba

Comment: Thank you but that procedure is too complicated for my knowledge

Answer (score -1):

If you're ok with using a DLL and rewrite your code, you can run Microsoft's Edge browser (a Chrome-based browser) with VBA. With that you can do almost anything you want. Note however, that access to the DOM is performed by *javascript*, not by an object like
*Dim IE As New InternetExplorer*. Look at the VBA sample and you'll get the grasp.

https://github.com/peakpeak-github/libEdge

Sidenote: Samples for C# and C++ are also included.