# Unable to get table on webpage in excel - innerhtml response does not have contents of the table

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

I am trying to get a table from webpage (url mentioned in the code) using XMLHTTP but the response what I get from the code does not contain the table.

The webpage has few buttons and I need to click that before getting result in excel.
First I need to click the **Run Scan button**
Then I need to click **Volume Table header** and sort it descending
and finally extract the table in excel

I also tried an alternate way of copying the contents by clicking the **Copy button** which is available on the webpage and paste it in excel but could not get the correct syntax to work.

Please help.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetTable()
    Dim sResponse As String, html As HTMLDocument
    Set html = New HTMLDocument
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://chartink.com/screener/evening-star", False
        .send
        sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    End With
    html.body.innerHTML = sResponse
    Debug.Print sResponse
    'ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 1).PasteSpecial
End Sub
```

## EDIT

Now I tried to open IE and then fetch the table contents but it give runtime error 438, object doesnt support this property or method on the `For Each` line. One strange thing is that when I tried to open a seperate IE window and then opened the link (without vba), it does not even load the full page. Javascript and other scripts are enabled. I am using IE8. I have been trying hard to get this work done but not getting success. I request some assistance to get the desired output

```
Sub REQUESTXML()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
    Dim elem As Object
    Dim x As Long
    
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate "https://chartink.com/screener/evening-star"
    
    Do While IE.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop
    Do Until IE.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop
    
    x = 1
    For Each elem In IE.document.getElementsByID("table table-striped scan_results_table dataTable no-footer")
        Sheets(1).Range("A" & x).Value = elem.innerText
        x = x + 1
    Next elem

    IE.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: Without analyzing the page, the table is probably read by a javascript. 
Read answer to a similar question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66045395/scrape-with-xmlhttp/66047523#66047523

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have edited my question. Appreciate if you could look into it. Thanks

Comment: IE8? Well, nowadays we all use Chrome in one fashion or another. Most modern webpages block old browsers (like IE8)

Comment: i searched for some vba code available for chrome but I got some results pertaining to Selenium and python which i am not aware of at all... can u pls guide me to achieve this vba result using chrome in excel vba? Thanks